# How to add new dictionary into existed json file with dictionary?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a json file saved in local server, such as：

```
    {
      "user": "user1",
      "id": "21779"
    }
```

and I want to write another dict into this json file, I need new content like this:

```
    {
       {
         "user": "user1",
         "id": "21779"
       },
       {
         "user": "user2",
         "id": "21780"
       }
     }
```

Or:

```
     [
       {
         "user": "user1",
         "id": "21779"
       },
       {
         "user": "user2",
         "id": "21780"
       }
     ]
```

I try to use json.dump() to add the new element, but is displayed as:

```
    {
      "user": "user1",
      "id": "21779"
    }
    {
      "user": "user2",
      "id": "21780"
    }
```

It is not a valid json file.

How can I do use json.dump, json.load, or other methods?
Thanks for help me!

Comment: you can achieve the second condition by using list. Use ```list.append()```.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to read your `JSON` file and then convert it to `list` instead of `dict`. Then you just need to append to that list and overwrite your `JSON` file.

```
import json

data = json.load(open('data.json'))

# convert data to list if not
if type(data) is dict:
    data = [data]

# append new item to data lit
data.append({
  "user": "user2",
  "id": "21780"
})

# write list to file
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: Is there any way how to append new dictionary to list of dictionaries saved in json , without loading the whole json and then saving it again? I want to avoid loading whole json everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the list not with the dict , try the below one solution if its help

```
import json

def appendList():
    with open("test.json", mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        feeds = json.load(f)
        print(feeds)

    with open("test.json", mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as feedsjson:
        entry = { "user": "user3","id": "21574"}
        feeds.append(entry)
        print(json.dump(feeds, feedsjson))
```